# Best Approach in Creating MySQL Query for this

Tags: php, mysql

We need to create a program in PHP/MySQL that will display all the 'people', who have certain skill/s that may be needed during an event. Each person has at least a skill and with a rating of 1 - 5 depending on how skilled is that person for a specific skill. For example, John have 2 skills - painting and drawing. He is expert in painting so his rating for painting is 5 while rating of only 2 for drawing, for he can draw but not very good.

There are events that the admin can add, which contains the needed skills for that specific event. Each event will contain skills from only one to eight different skills. For example, the user will create an event called Art Class Tutorial and will then select from the pre-defined skills (provided by the program) which skills are needed for it. In this case for example, the admin selects Sculpting, Drawing and Painting. Next, the admin will need to find all the 'people' with the skills Sculpting OR Drawing OR Painting (so that they can participate in teaching in the event), in which ratings should not be below 3.

In this case, John should be displayed because he has a 5-star rating for painting even if his drawing is just 2-star. If for example, Bob has sculpting, drawing and painting but all of them have a rating of 2-star, Bob should not be displayed.

So my problem is this: how can I create a query for this since the program does not know how many skills an event needs and which skills are chosen? The combination of possibilities are too many for me to create if's for each possible combination.

By the way, in my table for each 'person', there exist the eight fields (one for each skill) which should contain each skill rating per skill. Rating 0 means not skill in that area.

Here is my current code on this:

```
function search_results($keywords){
   $returned_results = array();
   $where = "";

   $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
   $total_keywords = count($keywords);

   foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword){
      $where .= "`keywords` LIKE '%$keywords%'";
      if($key != ($total_keywords - 1)){
         $where .= " AND ";
      }
   }
$results = "SELECT `title`, LEFT(`description`, 70) as `description` , `url` FROM `articles` WHERE $where";
$results_num = ($results = mysql_query($results)) ? mysql_num_rows($results): 0;

if($results_num === 0){
   return false;
}else{

   while($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
      $returned_results[] = array(
      'title' => $results_row['title'],
      'description' => $results_row['description'],
      'url' => $results_row['url']

    );
}
return $returned_results;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do that:

- Create onto your database some entities like: event,skill,people.
- Previous tables have to be related with foreign key(s); So you'll probably have to build some "intermediate" entities (think to event/skill cardinality and skill/people).
- Now you can, for every event, query the DB an dinamically extract how many skills have to considered for that particular event
- At this point, you can create dinamically a string for your `WHERE` condition
- The trick is done

Hope it is clear and will help you

Edit (under question's author request)

Intermediate entities are "special" entities that have to be created when you have a relationship of n/m between two entities (or table, if you prefer refer to those in that way). So, if 'event' and 'skills' have a m/n cardinality (and they have!) you have to create a table (say r_event_skills) where the PK of 'r_event_skills' is composed by combination of two foreign keys (one that is constrained to event's PK, the other constrained with skill's PK).
Now, you have to repeat the same for skill/people and the trick is done.

Comment: what do you mean by "intermediate" entities? if you can, please relate/compare it with my example above.. thanks!

Comment: I guess what I am trying to achieve is:

if there are 2 skills in an activity, the query should be
SELECT name, skill1, skill2, skillrate1, skillrate2 from table where Skillrate1 > 2 and skillrate2 > 2 

if there are 3 skills in an activity, the query should be
SELECT name, skill1, skill2, skill3, skillrate1, skillrate2, skillrate3 from table where Skillrate1 > 2 and skillrate2 > 2 and skillrate3 >2

and so on... however, I am having difficulties because there are quite a number of possible skills.

Comment: @BrandonYoung No no, slow down man. If you want to extract a list of people that could teach at the event, simply query DB for skills involved in that event. Once you have this, simply build a string by appending all values returned by query (this if the "rate level barriers" are fixed). If skill 1 have to be > 'x' , skill 2 have to be > 'y' and so on, consider a scenario where you have to build another entity in DB for keep this information and extract dinamically with query.

Comment: We were actually able to store the skills needed in an event in an array. please check my updated code above to see the specific code that we did.

Comment: @BrandonYoung : I don't understand why you don't follow my hint... I tell you the best way imho for make it dinamic.

Comment: that is what we are trying to do.. let us put it this way, can you point us to a link where there is the actually code on how to do the dynamic thingy?

Comment: I suppose that you have write your own code from scratch, so no, it isn't a code where i can link you..

Comment: well, i appreciate your effort but I really need to see exactly how it work.. i am quite new in this php/mysql so I may not understand everything easily.. if you may, please check my updated code again, if what you are saying is what we are also trying to do based on my understanding in your answer.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps

```
People's table
People_id People_name

skill's table
skill_id skill

listing table
people_id skill_id rating
```

then for each event

```
select people_name from people where people_id in
(SELECT people_id FROM listing WHERE 
skill_id in (8,9,10) and (rating >=3 or rating =5) order by rating desc)
 limit `NOpersonRequired
```

Comment: is the (8,9,10) the id of the skill?

Answer (score 0):

Updated according to the updated question:

I would create a DB with 5 tables:

- People (containing the peoples)
- Skills (containing all possible skills)
- PeopleSkill (containing for each people, for each skill, a score)
- Event (containing the events created by the admin)
- EventSkillsRequired (contains an evenid and a skill id)

The admin can create an Event into the Event table. He then creates EventSkillsRequired records with the event id and one of the skill id's needed for the event.

You need to create a php page that accepts an eventid. The following query return all people which have at least one skill with a skill score > 3 required for the event.

```
SELECT People.firstname, People.lastname, Skills.name, Skills.score FROM People 
INNER JOIN PeopleSkill ON PeopleSkill.peopleid = People.peopleid 
INNER JOIN Skills ON Skills.skillsid = PeopleSkill.skillsid 
INNER JOIN EventSkillsRequired ON EventSkillsRequired.skillid = Skills.skillsid
WHERE PeopleSkill.score > 3 AND EventSkillsRequired.eventid = ${php evenid parameter}
```

Comment: I've updated the query a bit. 1 'People' can have multiple 'skills' (n). 1 'Skill' can be linked to multiple 'People' (n). The PeopleSkill table is the normalization of this People - Skills n - n relationship (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @JohanB what if the event only requires one skill and another event requires five skills? there should only be a common query to execute either case. is it possible to have only one query to handle all the possible cases?

Comment: You need to adapt the where clause based upon the required skills. Think about it, you need to tell the database if you want to select the Sculpting skill or the Drawing skill or both.

Comment: @BrandonYoung i've updated my answer according to the changed question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 3 entities;

• 'people' with basic info such as name, contact details, etc

• 'skill' which lists the 8 different skills

• 'peopleskill' which acts as a link between the two, with an extra attribute 'Rating' showing their proficiency in associated skill.

So you could have in peopleskill, for example:

PERSON    SKILL RATING

1 1 5

1 2 2

and so on. The code I imagine would then resemble something like this.

```
$result = mysql_query=("SELECT * FROM peopleskill WHERE Skill_ID = $optionone OR $optiontwo OR $optionthree");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $personid = $row['Person_ID'];
    $rating = $row['Rating'];
    if($rating=>3){

        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE Person_ID = $personid");
        while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

            echo $row2['First_Name'];

        }
    }
}
```

Apologies for the layout of this post, I have no idea how to get this formatting sorted, but hopefully you get what I mean.

Comment: i got what you meant.. but basically, what I am trying to know is how can a query process events that require 3 skills and another event that require 8 skills? in your example, it seems like assuming the event only needs 3 skills